# How to lookup a value and Index Match Table if a Date is between 2 dates with criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to look up first ID match with second ID, if found then match first date with the given range date within same raw and then add type of leave according to the first date if matched

by using Vlookup / Match index /if

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that you want? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Sorry i do not  have  any set of formula , as  i need to have possible suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns shown are A to H, starting in row 1, this is the formula for C2:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$7,MATCH(1,(A2=$E$2:$E$7)*(B2>=$G$2:$G$7)*(B2<=$H$2:$H$7),0))
```

Note that this is an array formula. For it to work, you need to double click in cell C2 so you're in edit mode, then paste in the formula, then press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER to save the formula.

You'll need to adjust the references to columns E,F,G and H to include all rows. Remember to press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER each time.